# Sticky Footer Issue - Scrollbar appearing on smaller screens

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I'm using http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ for the footer of two sites I'm working on. Seems to be fine on a large monitor, no issues at all.

However when going to a smaller monitor and shrinking the page size down I'm getting a scroll bar at the bottom of the screen and the Footer is not stretching the full width of the screen.

A working example of this issue is [here](http://www.koodoocreative.co.uk/~lovelyla)

Just shrink the screen size down and you can see the issue.

Any ideas on how I can fix this. It has also happened on this [site](http://dev.harpersenvironmental.co.uk/) I've made

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a `min-width` for your footer. Currently the footer is correctly adjusting itself to the size of your screen, even if the rest of the content no longer fits on the screen and scrollbars are added.

Find the width at which scrollbars appear and set your footer's `min-width` to that. Example:

```
.footer {
    min-width: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Yup, thats done the trick. The scrollbars are now appearing when the content of my page goes off the screen. Which is a bit of a problem especially the cloud on the top right of the screen